# How would uneducated people say: "he has some good qualities"

Tags: word-request, informal-language

I have this thought that uneducated people wouldn't use the word "quality" when describing people's personalities such as helpful, mean, grouchy and hardworking.

So how would uneducated people say:

> "*he has some good qualities*"

Or am I wrong?

Comment: What sort of "uneducated person"? From what region? Some one from Appalachia will likely use a different phrase than someone from the north of England or New South Wales.

Answer (score 2):

'Uneducated' is a very subjective term. Depending on who uses it, it could refer to anything from people who have never been to school to people who have received an education that th speaker considers to be inferior in some ways to their own.

In any case, 'quality' in the sense of people' characteristics/personality is not a particularly *educated person's* word. 'Point' might be a less formal word - *He has some good points.*

Comment: +1 point! for "good points". Let's say people with no high school education (now I see your point regarding the subjected opinion). Why not consider both, people that never been (went??) to school and people that never had highschool education!

Comment: Incidentally, how would you say the example above, Tunny?

Comment: I'd say "He has some good qualities". I imagine that doesn't help, because I wouldn't call myself uneducated.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with: 'he has some good sides'

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of why this is a good choice; answers without explanation aren't particularly helpful. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](//meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.

Answer (score 1):

> He's not half-bad.
>
> He's not all bad.
>
> He might be a <somewhat derogatory noun>, but he's *our* <somewhat derogatory noun>.

For example:

> He might be an S.O.B., but he's *our* S.O.B.